# Android Studio Setup and UI issues

Tags: ide, android-studio, project-structure

1. I recently started watching a getting started video on youtube

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZddHwDYqyIw

and I followed him to where he opens Main_Activity.xml, I am not able to find the design/text tabs, I looked everywhere (I use the same build he does), I am not sure if Tool Windows>Designer will bring me to that, but even if i did, it is disabled, I am not able to click it!

1. Another issue is I get and IDE error ONLY when I create a new fresh project,

IDE Internal Error occured

```
IllegalStateException: Cant target data of key 'IdeaAndroidProject'. Given Class loaders: [PluginClassLoader[org.jetbrains.android, 10.0]]: Cant deserialize target data of Key 'IdeaAndroidProject'
```

//event log

```
3:14:34 AM IllegalStateException: Can't deserialize target data of key 'IdeaAndroidProject'. Given class loaders: [PluginClassLoader[org.jetbrains.android, 10.0]]: Can't deserialize target data of key 'IdeaAndroidProject'. Given class loaders: [PluginClassLoader[org.jetbrains.android, 10.0]]
```

1. Project 'structure'/layout

In the video, the presentor has a exploror type layout to browsw through his projects, all I see in mine (when I select the project tab on top left)is

```
Project (Down arrow)
  build.gradle
  gradlew
  gradlew.bat
  local.properties
  settings.gradle
  External Libraries
```

nothing else, on top of that it has a type of address bar, but that is not what I want,

Picture of erros as reference: http://postimg.org/image/esd6e4wol/

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: any solution ? same problem here... :((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close, reopen, check

> View>Windows>"Project Manager/Browser"

of sorts.

If not, redownload, and you should have your default setup!

Answer (score 7):

Even if you just downloaded it, make sure you have the last version of Android Studio (0.2.9 at the moment). You can check in Help > Check for Updates.

After that, delete that project and try to create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

I must ask you for your Android Studio Build number and your system environment. But I think the following step may help. And sorry for poor English if there is any spell mistake.

Under Windows 7 x64
Android Studio 130.737825

First,check your Android Studio version . I have the problem when the version is 130.737825  . Anyway update Android Studio.  "Help->Check for Update"

if it didn't work.

http:// tools.android.com/recent

to check the newest Build Number or

http:// dl.google.com/android/studio/patches/updates.xml

check the newest version .  (Sorry I cannot put more than two links)

Download Update package
like this one https://dl.google.com/android/studio/patches/AI-130.737825-132.821530-patch-win.jar
Please according to your own situation choose to down the right one. The format is AI-$FROM-$TO-patch-win.jar  $From is the build number your Android studio.  $TO is the newest build number you want to update.

Download the package to your Android Studio directory. D:\Android\android-studio.
Run cmd

```
D:\Android\android-studio>java -classpath AI-130.737825-132.821530-patch-win.jar com.intellij.updater.Runner install .
```